# Using canvas to download an image increases the file's size

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas

When I try to manipulate an image using a canvas, without any modifications, my image's filesize becomes significantly larger than the original.

Can you explain why this happens and how I can avoid this, please?

https://jsfiddle.net/95rnh4yj/

```
function one(selector) {
  return document.querySelector(selector);
}

function on(element, event, listener) {
  element.addEventListener(event, listener);
}

function blobToUrl(blob) {
  return Promise.resolve(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
}

function urlToImg(url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    let
    img = new Image();

    img.src = url;

    on(img, 'load', function (event) {
       resolve(event.target);
    });
  });
}

function imgToBlob(img) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    let
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
    canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
    context.fillStyle = 'transparent';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.save();
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    canvas.toBlob(resolve, 'image/jpeg', 1);
  });
}

function writeSrc(src) {
  one('a').href = src;
}

on(one('input'), 'change', function(event) {
  blobToUrl(event.target.files[0])
  .then(urlToImg)
  .then(imgToBlob)
  .then(blobToUrl)
  .then(writeSrc);
})
```

Comment: Do you mean the file size is bigger? Data doesn't generally weigh much. I jest, of course. After trying out your code, I see an image increased in size 5 times. In-browser Javascript probably just isn't very good at image manipulation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your problem is the file size then change your quality setting.

Currently you set this to 100. Change it to e.g. 0.95

```
function imgToBlob(img) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    let
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
    canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
    context.fillStyle = 'transparent';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.save();
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    canvas.toBlob(resolve, 'image/jpeg', 0.95); // <-----
  });
}
```

> Try to omit the quality setting and see if this works:

```
function imgToBlob(img) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    let
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
    canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
    context.fillStyle = 'transparent';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.save();
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    canvas.toBlob(resolve, 'image/jpeg');
  });
}
```

Omitting the quality setting produces the best results for me ([Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oajqo18q/2/)).

```
148kb -> 154kb (jpeg to jpeg)
102kb -> 119Kb
```

Comment: Thanks but, always bigger... and I don't understand why I can't preserve the original quality.

Comment: I dont think there is a way to guess the original compression :/

Comment: Thanks. Based on my tests, I need around .85 to keep the same size or less.

Comment: @Lcf.vs That will depend on which image was used. I don't know what the use case of this function is, but bear in mind you'll get an altered quality unless you find out what the compression rate was in the first place.